# EntityManager. Does Flush() save data in database as Commit()?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have already looked through a number of topics about **entityManager.flush()** method. 
In my practice I always have used *persist()* and *commit()* methods.

Also I have found that sometimes *flush()* automatically executes during *select* request to database and at this point it checks for example constraints of database so if persisted objects is wrong due to constraints during *select* an exception will be thrown.

Actually I would like to understand:

1. When you do *flush()* method then does a persisted data become saved in database? So you don't need to do *commit()* after *flush()*?
2. What is the advantages of using *flush()* instead of *commit()*, may be in some concrete cases?

Comment: persist() just tells the entity manager: this will have to be saved some time, before the end of the transaction. flush() executes the insert/update/delete statements needed to replicate the in-memory changes into the database. Commit commits the transaction, to make all these changes permanent, and visible to other transactions.  flush() does nothing more than just executing SQL statements. Just like you would do if you used JDBC.

Comment: Thank you. You have a huge reputation and a lot of knowledges I think. I have already read pretty such answer somewhere but may be due to my small experience I don't understand what is about.  I don't understand what insert/delete/update statements might execute flush(), because I don't set any. I just have seen that sometimes flush() used instead of commit(). So could you please answer in more details for 2 points in my question. Especially if I do flush() instead of commit() will my data be saved in database without futher commiting? Do I need to do commit() after using flush()?

Comment: You don't execute any statement because JPA executes them for you. When you load an entity via em.get(), it executes a SQL statement for you, to load the data from the database, right? That returns a managed entity (let's say a User). Now if you do `user.setName("Kirill")`, then you modify the object in memory, but JPA will also have to modify the corresponding row in the database, right? That's the whole point of JPA.

Comment: It can't execute an update statement every time you call a setter: that would lead to horrible performance. So it remembers the changes in memory. flush() tells JPA to execute the necessary changes in the database. All the changes made in memory are written to the database, using insert/update/delete statements. But these changes can still be rollbacked until the transaction is committed.

Comment: Ok. So to save my data permanently in database I must do commit() after flush()?

Comment: You almost never have to flush() explicitly. By default, JPA flushed for you just before the commit. Committing a transaction is always necessary, whatever API you use to make changes in a transactional database. That's the whole principle of transactions.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Now I have an understanding. May I ask you one more question - if I do flush() then do other transactions see the flushed data (if default isolation level of Oracle is used)?

Comment: flush() just executes insert, update and delete statements. The isolation level applies to these statements as for any other statements executed. So, if the isolation level is READ_COMMITTED, for example, then other transactions will only see committed data. flush() doesn't commit. It executes insert, delete and update statements.

Comment: Thank you. If you like and have a time you could form the answer that I will accept, may be it will help somebody else. If you don't have a willing I would create an answer based on your comments with the reference to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to JB Nizet now there is some clearity about *flush()*.

Here is some points:

1. To save data in database permanently JPA needs to insert data using
   insert/update/delete statements and then commit this data.
   Committing a transaction is always necessary.
2. *Flush()* method executes only insert/update/delete statements without commiting the data, so the transaction and data can be rolled back.
3. When you do *commit()* JPA flushes data before the commit i.e. *flush()* method is executed.
4. During *flush()* constraints in database are checked as it executes sql-statements and place data into database.
5. When isolation level set at READ_COMMITTED data after executing flush() is not seen in other transactions as *flush()* doesn't commit data.

Comment: Very concise and insightful... great answer.